# Evaluating $\int \cos^2{x}dx$ without using the alternate form of half angle formula

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a way to evaluate $\int\cos^2xdx$ without using $\cos^2x=\frac12(1+\cos(2x))$?

Comment: Integration by parts: $u=\cos(x)$ and $dv=\cos(x) dx$

Comment: Ah I tried that and got $\frac12(x+\cos x \sin x)$ but I was marked wrong on symbolab

Comment: symbolab probably just doesn't recognise different expressions as equivalent. This is a limitation of any computerised marking of integration problems involving trigonometric integrands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int cos^2 xdx= x\cos^2 x+\int x(2\sin x\cos x)dx \text{     (Integration by Parts)} $$
$$=x\cos^2 x+\int x\sin 2xdx$$
Applying Integration by parts for $\int x\sin 2xdx$,
$$\int x\sin 2xdx =-x\times\frac{\cos 2x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int \cos 2xdx$$
$$= -x\times\frac{\cos 2x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x$$
Substituting this into I,
$$I=x\cos^2 x -\frac{x\cos 2x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x +C $$

Answer (score 0):

You could use the complex definitions of sine and cosine -

$$\cos x = \frac {e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}}{2}, \sin x = \frac {e^{ix}- e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$I = \int \frac {e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix} + 2}{4} dx = \frac {1}{4}\left(2x + \frac {e ^{2ix}}{2i} - \frac {e^{-2ix}}{2i}\right) = \frac {x}{2} + \frac {1}{4}\sin(2x) =$$

$$\boxed {\frac {x +\sin x \cdot \cos x }{2} } $$